# Turn screen off when inactive for time period in RHEL and Debian

Tags: gnome, screensaver

I want to turn the screen off when inactive for x minutes using commandline settings on RHEL and Debian distros of Linux. Any help?

I have done this with the following commands on Ubuntu and Centos:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

How to do the same on RHEL & Debian? Any help appreciated.

Comment: There are two different concepts - turning on a screensaver and turning off a display using DPMS. What do you want?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, Anyone is fine for me

Comment: DPMS settings can be modified with `xset` command, see manpage. When it comes to screesaver, I am afraid that every screensaver out there has a separate config

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried `xset` commands. But those are not working

Comment: It works the same on every distribution. However it depends on your desktop environment. These settings apply to Gnome but not to other environments. What environment are you using on RHEL and Debian? You can use Gnome on these distributions, but apparently you're using something else, you need to tell us what.

Comment: @Gilles, I m using Gnome only... Still I do not understand why these commands are not working.. I  have tried restarting the machine too... But no change in the behaviour

Comment: Different versions of Gnome maybe? What versions of these distributions are you running?

Comment: @Gilles, I m working on Fresh installs of OSes... So these will be default versions on those OSes...do the gnome settings vary for different versions of Gnome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turning off screen after a specified period of inactivity can be achieved by at least 2 methods: either using `xset` DPMS features or a screensaver such as `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver`.

### Xset:

First, check whether your hardware supports DPMS:

```
$ xset dpms force standby
```

Your display should go blank. Apart from `standby` you can also try `suspend` and `off`. If you know that your HW supports DPMS you can tell `xset` to activate DPMS after a number of seconds (from `man xset`):

> When numerical values are given, they set the inactivity period (in
>   units of seconds) before the three modes are activated.  The first
>   value given is for the `standby' mode, the second is for the`suspend'
>   mode, and the third is for the `off' mode.

So, doing that will make your display go blank after 3 seconds of inactivity:

```
$ xset dpms 3 3 3
```

Run this command and wait for 3 seconds. This setting is not retained across reboots so if it works, you can add this line to your X startup script such as `~/.xinitrc` or your window manager startup script. Notice that turning off a display with DPMS will not lock the screen, you need to use an external screensaver for that.

### screensaver

There are many screensavers to choose from and most of them has their own config file that is independent of `xset` DPMS settings and can lock screens so that you need to know the password to unlock it. Some screensavers, however, may influence DPMS settings. For example, `xscreensaver` can override `xset` settings.

Unfortunately, I don't use `gnome-screensaver` and I have no idea what screensavers are installed by default on RHEL or Debian so I can't help you here but if you're looking for a nice screensaver give `xscreensaver` a try. If you also want to run some nice pictures it has a number of `screensaver` themes to choose from, it can display video files and is highly customizable. Modify `lock` setting in `~/.xscreensaver` by hand or run `xscreensaver-demo` to set a period of inactivity after which a screensaver will lock the screen. After making this modification, run `xscreensaver` daemon command and wait to see if `xscreensaver` works correctly.

### X screen saver

There is also an X in-built screensaver that can be activated with `x set activate`. Type `xset q` and see how long you will have to wait for it to start under `Screen Saver` section:

> Screen Saver:   prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
>   timeout:  600    cycle:  600

In this case, you would have to wait for 600 seconds.
Run it now:

```
$ xset s activate
```

If you set it with `noblank` flag, it will display a pattern set with `xsetroot` when activated:

```
$ xset s noblank
$ /usr/bin/xsetroot -solid Green
$ xset s activate
```

Disable it altogether:

```
$ xset s off
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

Debian 8